# What's wrong with my MySQL syntax?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table `employee`:

```
+----+--------+
| Id | Salary |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 100    |
| 2  | 200    |
| 3  | 300    |
+----+--------+
```

Why does this query give me a syntax error?

```
with sub as (
select Salary from employee
order by Salary desc
limit 2
) 
select min(Salary) from sub;
```

The error message is

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sub as (
select Salary from employee
order by Salary desc
limit 2
)
select min(' at line 1
```

I tried reading the documentation for subquery, with clauses, and select syntax and could not figure out what I'm doing wrong. Does MySQL care about whitespace/new lines/capitalization in queries?

Comment: Please edit the question. Add the text of each error exactly as it comes from the query processor.

Comment: What's the version of Mysql?.No support for CTE lower than 8.0 version.Both queries works in 8.0 but second query fails in 5.6

Comment: `with` was introduced on MySQL V 8.0 +, so till 5.7 you can't use `with` instead try using a sub query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your query.
I already tested in my mariadb database version 10.2.25 and it works
Please check your mysql version. If you want to use mysql, please upgrade to mysql version 8
If you want to switch to mariadb, make sure version minimal 10.2